# Svg doesn't work as background

Tags: html, css, svg, textures, adobe-illustrator

I made a translucent svg. It was a 50% opacity round metal texture. When I put it above any other color it makes it look like real metal. It was made using Illustrator and had 2 of its effects: Pixelate>Mezzotint>GrainyDots and Blur>RadialBlur. Then I made a Clipping Mask. Here is its link https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99185097/metalTex.svg. When I normally open it, it views correctly, but when I use it as a background in CSS3 for my HTML5 page, it doesn't open. I am sure it's not my CSS coding's fault because when I use another very simple svg as my background, it opens. I think it could be the Illustrator effects, maybe they don't view when you use it as a background. Also these effects make it of 4.46mb. Please suggest a solution. Making it a png wouldn't work because sometimes it needs to cover extremely long pages.

Comment: Are you using Chrome or Safari. I so try Firefox or Opera. I think you've come across the Webkit bug that means that background images can't themselves contain images.

Comment: Thanks but how I am I supposed to run it on others

Comment: I mean how could I make the .svg I created run with all browsers i.e Chrome, Safart, Opera and Firefox.

Comment: Plus, it even ain't working in firefox when I use background-size:cover;

Comment: Unless you fix the webkit bug (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99677) or stop using images in your background you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Please **expand** your vector file properly, save and then export it as svg file again and go for background. It may work now.